# Using declared f variable in a for cycle outside the cycle. Java

Tags: java, variables, for-loop

Question is simple and answer may be simple too. Lets say that I begin a for cycle.

```
for(int yourCont = 0; yourCont < myCont; yourCont++){}
```

I could use the integer yourCount to do some tasks inside of the for cycle.

```
int theForTask = 2;
for(int yourCont = 0; yourCont < myCont; yourCont++){

    theForTask + yourCont;
}
```

But If I came to use it outside the for cycle keys...

```
for(int yourCont = 0; yourCont < myCont; yourCont++){
      //YOUR BEATIFUL CODE
}
    theForTask + yourCont;
```

It would say that there isn't a variable called "yourCont". Why is that, I mean it has no sense using the counter variable outside the for cycle, but in strict rules you could, unless for cycle was considered a class or a method and the variable you declare is private, but I don't think that is the case. So in resume:

**Why can't we use the for's counter variable outside the cycle?**

Comment: The variable is declared within the loop, thus its scope is only the loop. You want to use it outside the loop? Declare it outside the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables declared inside a `for` loop are scoped to that loop. If you want to use it afterwards, declare it outside of the loop:

```
int yourCont = 0;
for (; yourCont < myCont; yourCont++) {
    // ...
}

System.out.println(yourCont);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the way you have defined the variable is local to the for loop scope. So once you are out of that loop you won't get anything